# How to resolve org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException in SpringBatch

Tags: java

`springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException` while trying to select the data from the sql server database, here is the code I have written. Can anybody suggest how to select data from database using query interface?

```
public int getRedempRequestId(RedemptionResponseBean redemptionResponse)
        throws ParseException {
    final Timestamp redempIdFromCsv = getRedeemDate(redemptionResponse);
    int participantId = redemptionResponse.getOcpEventMemberId();
    System.out.println(redempIdFromCsv);
    System.out.println(participantId);

    int res = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("SELECT RR.REDEMPTION_REQUEST_ID "
            + "FROM  dbo.REDEMPTION_REQUEST RR WITH (NOLOCK)"
            + "WHERE RR.SENT_DATE = ? AND "
            + "RR.OEDEF_OCP_EVENT_MEMBER_ID = ? ", new Object[] {
            redempIdFromCsv, participantId });
    System.out.println(res+"-----------");
    return res;
}
```

could anybody tell me what's the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure that query actually returns any data?

Comment: why is there any issue with query,i'm expecting no of rows with the matching criteria?

Answer (score 11):

If you expect no data to be returned, you shouldn't use `jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(...)`, since that method expects the query it will execute **will** return an integer value. Basically, that is what the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is telling you; its Javadoc says:

> Data access exception thrown when a result was expected to have at least one row (or element) but zero rows (or elements) were actually returned.

Instead, you should use one of the `query(...)` methods from `JdbcTemplate`, which allow for zero rows to be returned.